# System process constantly between 20-30% cpu usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

I've reinstalled Windows 10 onto my Acer Aspire V5 laptop and have noticed that it starts to get laggy - where I'll move the mouse/type/click on something and it will take a few seconds to respond.

I've gone onto task manager and noticed that the System Process is constantly between 20-30% which in turn, for some reason, has the CPU around 95-99%.

I have had a look over the past few days on ways to resolve this like updating the drivers and checking for updates. It isn't causing too much of an issue but would be good if it wasn't lagging as much

Thanks

Comment: Likely updating Windows Search index or performing background virus scan. It may take a few days after reinstallation, but should reduce CPU use eventually.

Comment: Can you capture a trace by running from an admin command prompt:  wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile.  Wait 30 seconds while you have the issue and then stop it with: wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.Etl. You can open gp.etl in Windows Performance analyser which you can get from the MS Store or ADK/SDK. Focus on CPU sampled. Look at the modules and stacks inside the system process.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippin I've disabled the windows search indexer and stopped the background virus scan and still seems to be running slow?